# Scroll through anchor tags with next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, anchor

I am trying to make a scrolling text box that has a next and previous button to scroll the user to the next/previous anchor tag in the text.

I was looking at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/T5FgG/ and like the way it accelerates/decelerates but it doesn't work when I insert it into a text area http://jsfiddle.net/T5FgG/16/

```
<button id="jumpbut">Next</button>

<div style="height:120px;width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <a name="a">A target</a>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>        
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <a name="B">B target</a>
</div>
```

I eventually want to use Bootstrap to prettify this. If bootstrap has something or an extension that can already achieve this, please let me know.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like below.

```
 $(function() {
  var $anchors = $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])'),target = $anchors.first(),current=0;
  $("#jumpbut").on("click",function() {
    $('#test').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 2000,'swing');
    target = $anchors.eq(current+1);
  });
});
```

Updated Jsfiddle for your reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/T5FgG/18/